# onSaveInstanceState всегда null

Tags: android, kotlin

При переключении активити данные не сохраняются

MainActivity

```
binding.imageButton2.setOnClickListener { val image_intent = Intent(this, ImageActivity::class.java)
    startActivity(image_intent)}
```

ImageActivity

```
var prompt: String? = "qq"
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    Log.d("AAAAA", "onCreate")
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_image)
    binding1 = ActivityImageBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
    setContentView(binding1.root)

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        binding1.textView.text = savedInstanceState.getString("key")

    }
    else
        println("save = null")
binding1.imageButton.setOnClickListener { val main_intent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        startActivity(main_intent) }
}
 
override fun onSaveInstanceState(outState: Bundle) {
    binding1.generate.setOnClickListener {
        outState.putString("key", prompt)}
    Log.d("AAAAA", "onSave = $prompt")
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState)}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    Log.d("AAAAA", "onResume")
    binding1.generate.setOnClickListener {
        prompt = binding1.textView.text.toString() + 1
        binding1.textView.text = prompt.toString()
    }
```

Log

```
D/AAAAA: onCreate             ------открыл 2е активити, несколько раз нажал кнопку
I/System.out: save = null
D/AAAAA: onResume

D/AAAAA: onSave = TextView111111     ------перешел в 1е активити
D/AAAAA: onStop

D/AAAAA: onCreate
I/System.out: save = null          -----вернулся во 2е активити, TextView не сохранилась
D/AAAAA: onResume
```

Что сделать чтоб значения сохаранялись при переходе в другое активити и обратно?

Comment: **Во-первых**, вы не возвращаетесь, а запускаете новый экземпляр. **Во-вторых**, в `onSaveInstanceState` вы вешаете обработчик на кнопку, которая уже не будет нажата и в `outState` ничего не записывается. **В-третьих**, механизм восстановления работает только для случаев убийства активности системой, но не юзером или самим приложением.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Я запускаю новый экземпляр согласен, во втором пункте я убрал кнопку, не помогло. Как мне сделать чтоб при открытии 2го активити данные восстанавливались?

Comment: При каких условиях они должны восстанавливаться? При каждом запуске? - читайте про [`SharedPreferences`](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences)

Comment: Разобрался в данном вопросе, спасибо за помощь